# Selecting a changing number of variables to set up a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, database, function, dictionary, args

I have the following variables

```
city     = 'Chicago'
country  = 'USA'
state    = 'Illinois' 
dates    = ['1/1/2013', '1/1/2014', '1/1/2015']
var1     = [4.5, 6.5, 7]
lake     = 'Michigan'
```

and I would like to write a function in order to create a dictionary with only a number of the aforementioned variables, e.g. `city`, `state`, `dates` and `var1` and this number should change arbitrarily.

Let us consider the following example to clarify my idea.

I define the function:

```
def funct(**args)
    return args
```

so that, if I arbitrarily choose

```
funct(city = 'Chicago', lake = 'Michigan', var1 = [4.5, 6.5, 7])
```

I get

```
{'city': 'Chicago', 'lake': 'Michigan', 'var1': [4.5, 6.5, 7]}.
```

The problem is that I would like to avoid to write `city = 'Chicago', lake = 'Michigan', var1 = [4.5, 6.5, 7]` everytime in the arguments, indeed I would prefer to set a priori a long list of variables then build a customized dictionary recalling only the objects I like, e.g.

```
newfunct(city, state, country)
```

to get the output

```
{'city': 'Chicago', 'state': 'Illinois', 'country': 'USA'}
```

or

```
newfunct(lake, city)
```

to get the dictionary

```
{'lake': 'Michigan', 'city': 'Chicago'}.
```

I hope I have explained clearly my issue.

Thanks in advance to everyone will provide comments or suggestions.

Comment: Someone will break me on this one, but i don't think this is possible. Because the passed object doesn't really have a name unless you perhaps previously assigned a name to it (like you would do if you wrapped the variable in a custom class object). But you could use positional arguments instead and predefined the order of which they have to be added? But then you wouldn't be able to pass in your second option of `lake, city` obviously.

Comment: You might be better of solving your issue further up your code base, for instance how do you get to the point where you get `city = 'Chicago'`? Could you perhaps put that result in a dictionary in that part of the code directly? Most of those things comes from CVS files or a databse, and storing the `key` as a dictionary key right then and there is often better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have dictionary containing all the `key:value` pairs required, Now you create a function `newfunc()` and iterate over it's parameters to retrieve it's values from the given dictionary, and then zipping the results again to create a dictionary.

```
d = {"city" : 'Chicago', "country"  : 'USA', "state" : 'Illinois', "dates" : ['1/1/2013', '1/1/2014', '1/1/2015'], "var1" :[4.5, 6.5, 7], "lake" : 'Michigan'}

def newfunc(*args):
    return {i: d.get(i, None) for i in args}

print newfunc("city", "country")
```

Output:

```
{'city': 'Chicago', 'country': 'USA'}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This will be helpful!

Comment: I am sorry. Unfortunately, it seems that I should have reputation '15' in order to upvote. I am a newbye of stackoverflow. As soon as I get this upgrade I will upvote your contribution for sure! :) Thanks

Comment: I would recommend passing `d` as a parameter to the function instead of just relying on it being in the same scope as the function.

Comment: I already upvoted IanAuld's comment, but think it's important enough to repeat: this *only* works because `d` is global. As soon as you put this code in a function like `main`, it won't work. You need to have the dictionary passed into the function as well.

Comment: But in the context of the question asked : *indeed I would prefer to set a priori a long list of variables then build a customized dictionary recalling only the objects* So Defined it as global since no other functions are accessing it, and its contents are never changed in the course of execution.

Comment: @anmol_uppal For what it's worth, the down vote wasn't mine. I think your answer is fine, and since it was accepted by the asker, obviously he/she found it useful. I just wanted to make sure that he/she (and future readers) understands that making the dictionary global is an absolute requirement, not just a suggestion, for this code to work.Do keep in mind though, that you don't know the rest of the asker's code base; making the dictionary global might be a bad idea for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, if you have to do this, your code shall be changed for a more pythonic approach, but since you asked, here is my solution:

```
city = 'Chicago'
country = 'USA'
state = 'Illinois'
dates = ['1/1/2013', '1/1/2014', '1/1/2015']
var1 = [4.5, 6.5, 7]
lake = 'Michigan'

def newfunct_by_val(*args):
    return {k:v for k, v in globals().iteritems() for i in args if v == i}

def newfunct_by_name(*args):
    return {i: globals()[i] for i in args}

print newfunct_by_val(city, state, country)
print newfunct_by_name('city', 'state', 'country')
```

Output:

```
{'city': 'Chicago', 'state': 'Illinois', 'country': 'USA'}
{'city': 'Chicago', 'state': 'Illinois', 'country': 'USA'}
```

From what I understood, you need a function that will have as arguments the variable names and you don't want to define other dictionaries, etc.

If is this indeed what you need, then the `newfunct_by_val` function is your solution. This function searches the globals() dictionary for all the variables (more exactly: keys) with the values equal to the values of the of the variables passed as arguments. It has a drawback: **if multiple global variables have the same value then it will generate a dictionary containing all of them**. This is why I would not recommend this solution.

If you agree to call the function with the names of the global variables as strings, then the `newfunct_by_name` does the trick.

Please note that both functions may fail if one or more of the arguments are not *variable* names. E.g.: print `newfunct_by_val(zipcode)` or `newfunct_by_name('zipcode')`. In this case they will raise the `KeyError` exception.

Comment: Thank you Sorin for this contribution. Actually `newfunct_by_val` fits even better with my needs.

Comment: You can  search by id of value instead of searching all variables in `globals()` with specific value. So, i recommend to use  `id(v) == id(i)` . This hint is for  `newfunct_by_val()` function